# jqGrid Search column sort

Tags: search, jqgrid

I have a grid,
when you click on search from the bottom navigator this search will popup by default, all the columns and by default starting from left to right.

Is there any way I can change that? For example instead of `Inv No` by default it will become always the date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good question! There are currently no [option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asinge_searching#options) of the searching dialog where the default searching column could be specified.

As the workaround I would suggest to use `filters` property of the `postData` option of jqGrid. For example [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SetDefaultSearchingField.htm) opens "closed" column with "Yes" selected by default. It uses

```js
postData: {
    filters: JSON.stringify({
            groupOp: "AND",
            rules:[{
                field: "closed",
                op: "eq",
                data: "true"
            }]
        })
}
```

where the filed value (`"closed"`) is the `name` of the column (`"eq"`) is one from allowed operation for the column (I used `sopt: ['eq', 'ne']` in the demo for the column) and the value of `data` ("true") should specify the default value for the searching field. In the most cases you will use `data: ""` probably.

Comment: @Ray: You are welcome! If I will not forget it I will post my suggestion to trirand where additional new options of the searching dialog will allow to specify column name which should be displayed (like `defaultField: "closed"`). Probably it would be practical to be able to specify the *order* of columns in `<select>` with column names, but it's not so important as the default searching field.